# using jquery plugin in another jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created plugin which do particular things with data, now I would like somehow join my plugin to use if with ex. jQuery dialog. How can I do this?

this is simplified situation:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.jquerytoc = function(map, layersConfig, layersList) {

        var opts = $.extend($.treeview, $.fn.jquerytoc.defaults, map, layersConfig, layersList);

        var TOC = {
            map : opts.map,
            layersConfig : opts.layersConfig,
            TOCinfos : {},
            getRequiredData : function() {

            },
            init : function() {
                this.getRequiredData();
            }
        };
        var HTML = {
            nodes : TOC.TOCinfos,
            data : [],
            htmlObject : {},
            jqTreeObject : {},
            setHTMLcode : function() {
                var object = this.data;
                var objectNode = {};

                var nodes = this.nodes;
                console.log(nodes);
                for (var node in nodes) {
                    objectNode = {};

                    objectNode.label = nodes[node].name;
                    objectNode.children = [];

                    var sublayers = nodes[node].sublayers;
                    for (var sublayer in sublayers) {
                        objectNode.children.push({
                            'label' : sublayers[sublayer]
                        });
                    };
                    object.push(objectNode);
                };
            },
            init : function(object) {
                this.htmlObject = object;
                this.setHTMLcode();
            }
        };
        function init() {
            TOC.init();
            HTML.init(this);
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            init();

//AND HERE I WOULD LIKE TO WRAP MY DOM ELEMENT WITH JQUERY DIALOG
jQuery.dialog(this);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

but I always get that jQuery method dialog is `undefined`. I tried it in many ways but always get same error. I would be glad for help! thanks! :)

Comment: have u included the jquery ui

Comment: I have included it in main html file before including my plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery(this).dialog()` instead of `jQuery.dialog(this)`